# Get nodes that are participating in any cycle in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

I have a problem that states the following :

> Given a cyclic graph , output for each node if the node removes all cycles in the graph.

The most trivial way to do this is using a Union-find disjoint set , and for each node , try **not** putting it in the Union-find disjoint set , if there are no cycles , then this node should output "Yes" , otherwise "No".

This approach would take about $\Theta(N^2)$ time and $\Theta(N)$ memory.

The problem also stated that $N \leq 1,000,000$ which would definitely get a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) Answer on any problem.

So, my question is, What's the algorithm that would take $\Theta(N \lg N) $ or $\Theta(N)$ time and $\Theta(N)$ memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use [Tarjan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29#Bridge-finding_algorithm) algorithm to find all of the bridges in the graph. Then remove all of them. Remaining graph should be made of some cycles, such that all of them have at least one common vertex, otherwise we can return false for all vertices. Is possible to check this with DFS, further reasoning is easy, total running time is $O(|V|+|E|)$.

Comment: do you mean that every edge that is not a bridge is participating in a cycle , so i remove all bridges, after that there should be one connected component bigger than 1 , if there is a solution , otherwise there is no solution , but how do I check for the common vertex between all cycles?

Comment: Yes, every edge which is not bridge participating in at least one cycle, this is actually definition of bridge. But I didn't wrote complete answer because I think this is homework or something and you should do it yourself, but for hint: again you know that either you have exactly one cycle or more than one, in the second case, you know that there exists at least one vertex with degree bigger than 2.

Comment: It's not a homework , actually I'm just self training for IOI, and I need this algorithm to know how to solve this kind of problem

Comment: I can't figure out the right method to find the common node, Can you tell me?

Comment: @mohammedessam, I think the hard part is tarjan algorithm, and we cannot expect to someone think about it without knowing that algorithm, but for the rest let think together, if the resulted graph ($G'$) is cycle then is clear, otherwise there should be a node of degree at least three, you can contract all vertices of degree two in $G'$ to make $G"$, then the $G"$ is either made of at most three vertex or more (with possibly parallel edges), in the second case we can return false (for all vertices except for some special vertices, for example if connected to all others)(why?).

Comment: In the first case you should reason it out yourself. (how to recover contracted edges). May be there is a simpler and more elegant algorithm, but using Tarjan algorithm and then edge contraction is first thing comes to mind.

Comment: I drew some graphs and it seems that the node with the most degree is the candidate, and I should just check for it using the method I stated above (using Union-find disjoint set), Is that right?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You know what is the [edge contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction)? Just in remaining graph run edge contraction to remove vertices of degree two. do not contract if you have a vertex of degree more than 2 in $G'$ (may be in $G"$ is of degree two).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9310/discussion-between-mohammed-essam-and-saeed-amiri)

Comment: My method merged with Tarjan worked , Thanks.

Comment: Very nice, good to see this.